# How to access the folder where the .exe is running Wix bootstrapper?

Tags: variables, wix, directory, installation, bootstrapper

I have a bootstrapper which I want to install its contents to the same directory as the bootstrapper .exe is being run in. This executable will then be run when the user presses the "LAUNCH" button. How do I reference this directory?

I am attempting to pass $(sys.CURRENTDIR) to the MSI via an MsiProperty, but looking at the log file, the CURRENTDIRECTORY and INSTALLFOLDER do not match.

CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Users\nickd\Desktop\WixTestingInstall\CW6
INSTALLFOLDER=C:\VB6\CW6\CW6.root\CW6\PreReqsInstaller\

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to make use of the burn built-in variables:

> WixBundleOriginalSource - gets the source path from where the bundle
>   originally ran. WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder - gets the folder from
>   where the bundle originally ran.

[WIX Built-In variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html)

***As commented below by @SeanHall, these variables are only available from WiX 3.9.526.0 version***

Do something like this:

```
    <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder]" />

<MsiPackage 
        Id="msiforinstall" 
        Compressed="yes" 
        SourceFile="sourcepath" 
        Vital="yes"> 
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" /> 
  </MsiPackage>
```

Comment: FYI, `WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder` was just added in the weekly build WiX 3.9.526.0.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was running 3.8.something but after updating and doing this it is working exactly as I wanted it to!

Comment: Is there a simple way to get this value *without* upgrading to a weekly (not-yet-production-stable) version?